# What is the alternative of com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute to run Doclet in jdk 11?

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

I am using JDK 11 on Apache netbeans 10.

The `main` method is depricated since java 9 and marked for a removal where there is no [alternative](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet/package-summary.html)

All of my attempts in command line ended up with

```
javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class Exception
```

When I try:

```
com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute (new String[]{"-doclet",TestVarElement.class.getName(),"C:\\Users\\Super3\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MyProject\\src\\pk\\TestVarElement.java"});
```

I get:

```
javadoc: error - Doclet class pk.TestVarElement does not contain a start method
```

`Start` method is depricated and replaced by `run` method, the previous set up is working for java 8 and older, I want the equivalent for 9,10,11.

I looked at the documentation for [DocumentationTool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/DocumentationTool.html) and the relevent materials but I did not find a single working example.

Is there any way we can run a Doclet/DocletEnvironment programmatically or a working example from commandline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming what you're trying to do is run Javadoc programatically, the [`jdk.javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/module-summary.html) module documentation describes ways to do so:

> #### *javadoc*
>
> This module provides the equivalent of command-line access to *javadoc* via the [ToolProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/ToolProvider.html) and [Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/Tool.html) service provider interfaces (SPIs), and more flexible access via the [DocumentationTool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/DocumentationTool.html) SPI.
>
> Instances of the tools can be obtained by calling [ToolProvider.findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/ToolProvider.html#findFirst(java.lang.String)) or the [service loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) with the name `"javadoc"`.

Based on your previous code, and your edit, you don't need the functionality of the `DocumentationTool` SPI. The `ToolProvider` SPI should suffice. As mentioned in the documentation (and by @AlanBateman in the comments) you can get the `ToolProvider` instance using the following:

```
ToolProvider javadoc = ToolProvider.findFirst("javadoc").orElseThrow();
```

You then call one of the `run` methods with the out/err streams of your choice and the desired arguments. The arguments are the same you'd use for the unsupported `Main.execute`  API you're currently using.

```
int result = javadoc.run(System.out, System.err, /* ... your args ... */);
```

Comment: Thank you for sources, But I was not able to create a working example from that, it needs a deep understanding to the language and field, wich I dont posses unfortinately.

Comment: `var javadoc = ToolProvider.findFirst("javadoc").orElseThrow()`. Then invoke `javadoc.run` with appropriate out/err streams and the parameters that you currently pass to the unsupported/JDK-internal Main.execute.